# How do I solve WITH syntax error in mysql code

Tags: mysql

I have a sql code but when I try to run it it always give me syntax error in the WITH part:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.GIS_TB01S004_OCEANOS (
  codigo       numeric  (3, 0)  NOT NULL ,
  nome         varchar  (50)        NULL ,
  sigla        char     (3)         NULL ,
  ext_km2      numeric  (11, 3)     NULL ,
  obs          varchar  (72)        NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT PK_GIS_TB01S004_OCEANOS PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (codigo  asc)
   WITH
    FILLFACTOR = 10,
  CONSTRAINT CK_GIS_TB01S004_OCEANOS_codigo CHECK
   (codigo between 1 and 7),
  CONSTRAINT CK_GIS_TB01S004_OCEANOS_sigla CHECK
   (sigla != ' ' and
    sigla not like '% %')
);
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong with it. Where's the syntax error in WITH?

Comment: It is MySQL or SQL-Server?? Because that looks like SQL-Server and it won´t work in MySql

Comment: I'm trying to run this code on MySQL but the code was made in sql server

Comment: So it won´t work. They are not the same

Comment: dammit, thanks for answering. I removed the with fillfactor = 10 and it worked, hope it won't be a problem later on but this'll have to do for now

Comment: Also note that the CHECK constraints won't be honored unless you're using MySQL 8.0. Earlier versions of MySQL accept CHECK constraint syntax but won't enforce those constraints.

Comment: `sigla not like '% %'` covered `sigla != ' '`.